# Form won't store data in POST

Tags: php, forms, post

I'm trying to mke a delete button by a simple form and php won't get any data from POST.

index.php

```
    echo '<tr style="background:green; border:1px solid black;"><td>' . date("d M y", strtotime($row["time"]))  . "</td>";
    echo "<td><b>" . $row["caseId"]. "</b></td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["snPaper"]  . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["snBox"] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row["snUnit"] . '</td>';
    echo '<td><form action="remove.php" mehod="post" id="delete"><input type="text" value="kokot" name="id" id="id" /><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Delete"></td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row["id"] . '</td></tr>';
```

remove.php

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
echo 'id=' . $id;
print_r($_POST);
// Create connection
$dir = 'sqlite:db.sqlite';

$conn = new PDO($dir) or die("hovno");

$conn->exec("'DELETE FROM favorite_apps WHERE id = '$id" );
```

Comment: You spelt method as mehod

Comment: If that has worked mark the answer below as the answer to save you more notifications

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your form method and it should work

```
<form method="post">
```

Instead of

```
<form mehod="post">
```

I've posted this just in case you didn't see the comment

Comment: Oh... Thanks. Havent noticed it :-)

Comment: If this has fixed it mark it as the answer so you don't keep getting notifications mate

Comment: It sends value, but as I have it in foreach, I need to match it to the row. It shows correct ID in the index.php but remove.php gets always the same value (lowest in the database).

Comment: My advise is to use a prepared statement due to your code being able to been attacked by injection, then I would then check what ID you are passing over and see if it is deleting the correct ID, if it doesn't then it is to do with your variables

Answer (score 0):

Try isset

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
// id index exists
```

}

Or you can also use

```
$id = isset($_POST['id']) ? $_POST['id'] : '';
```

And replace mehod with method in

```
<form method="post">
```

This will work

Comment: That check would work but he hasn't spelt method="post" correctly he has put mehod="post"

Comment: Yup he needs to replace mehod with method too